# VM resize from D4s_v3 E2s_v3?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have created one VM in azure with Standard D4s_v3. Due to the VM usage and cost reason I want ot change the VM size from D4s_v3 to E2s_v3? is it possible to change VM size?

Regards,
Durga.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the VM size. When considering the ability to resize virtual machines there are three key concepts that will impact how simple it is to change the size of your VM. Get more information from this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/).

Easily you can resize the VM size as the picture below path. From the overview of VM, you will see a new size.

[image]

Comment: Is my reply helpful?